# Extraer enteros entre dos cadenas en C

Tags: c

Necesito extraer una cadena de caracteres contenida entre dos cadenas distintas, en este caso "Media = " y "ms" para almacenar como variable la cifra que aparece de las estadísticas de cada ping.

Entiéndase que necesito almacenar sólo la cifra (sin la unidad final ms) para poder manipularla después.

El archivo de texto que abro contendría información de este tipo. Necesito almacenar exclusivamente el dígito correspondiente al final de la última línea:

```
Haciendo ping a 8.8.8.8 con 32 bytes de datos:
Respuesta desde 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 tiempo=11ms TTL=54
Respuesta desde 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 tiempo=11ms TTL=54
Respuesta desde 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 tiempo=11ms TTL=54
Respuesta desde 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 tiempo=11ms TTL=54

Estad¡sticas de ping para 8.8.8.8:
    Paquetes: enviados = 4, recibidos = 4, perdidos = 0
    (0% perdidos),
Tiempos aproximados de ida y vuelta en milisegundos:
    M¡nimo = 11ms, M ximo = 11ms, Media = 11ms
```

Adjunto, también, la parte de mi código que hace referencia al archivo:

```
fp = fopen("dns1.txt", "r");
while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp))
    if (strstr(line, term) != NULL) {
        subString = strtok(line, "Media =");
        subString = strtok(NULL, "ms");

        printf("the thing in between quotes is %s\n", subString);
    }
```

A partir de este código obtengo algo muy aproximado, pero además de la cifra me aparece un "o =" molesto que no me deja manipularla...

Comment: Deberías empezar por intentar leer línea a línea, de forma que no se corten de 9 en 9 caracteres. ¿ Como controlas que no se corten justo en mitad de la palabra `"Media"` o del número ?

Comment: Edito mi pregunta inicial dando más detalles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilizando sólo el string en el que necesitas buscar la media aquí te dejo un código que da como resultado el valor de la media, puedes adaptarlo a tu código

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    const char *s = "Minimo = 11ms, Maximo = 11ms, Media = 11ms ";

    const char *PATTERN1 = "Media =";
    const char *PATTERN2 = "ms";

    char *target = NULL;
    char *start, *end;

    if ( start = strstr( s, PATTERN1 ) )
    {
        start += strlen( PATTERN1 );
        if ( end = strstr( start, PATTERN2 ) )
        {
            target = ( char * )malloc( end - start + 1 );
            memcpy( target, start, end - start );
            target[end - start] = '\0';
        }
    }

    if ( target ) printf( "%s\n", target );

    free( target );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. A la hora de compilar me da problemas la línea         "if (start = strstr(s, PATTERN1))", no sé cómo solventarlo!

Comment: Qué error te da?

Comment: "No se puede asignar un valor de tipo "const char*" a una entidad de tipo "char*"."  Estaba intentando probar tu código antes de trastear a partir del mío propio pero me encuentro con ese escollo, a ver si me puedes echar un cable que me pilla un poco grande a mí, jajaja!

Comment: Ah, en la linea donde defino el string que quieres utilizar puse const char, quitale el const y ya: char *s = "Minimo = 11ms, Maximo = 11ms, Media = 11ms ";

Comment: "No se puede usar un valor de tipo "const char*" para inicializar una entidad de tipo "char*".", es lo que me dice ahora!

Comment: Nada, solucionado, funciona implementado, muchísimas gracias!!!!!

Comment: El código funciona perfecto. Sin embargo, se me ocurre una implementación y tal vez me puedas ayudar: si la IP no muestra conectividad y por ello no apareciera la cadena "Media = " de donde extraer la cifra, estaría bien printar error. Al implementar un "else" dentro del primer if me printa el error por cada línea leída en lugar de hacerlo al terminar el proceso de lectura. ¿Me puedes ayudar a printarlo únicamente una vez?

Comment: Tienes que implementar la función EOF(End of file). Si el archivo se termina y no hay media entonces imprime el error

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107756/discussion-between-santos-and-heytalepazguato).